# Azure B2C with Salesforce, missing "objectId"

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I'm testing Azure B2C with Salesforce as IdP, and the login process works fine from Salesforce perspective (Salesforce Identity Provider Event Log show "success" for sing-on attempts), but redirection back to simple testing web application ends up to error page such as

`/redirect.html#error=server_error&error_description=AADB2C90037%3a+An+error+occurred+while+processing+the+request.+Please+contact+administrator+of+the+site+you+are+trying+to+access.%0d%0aCorrelation+ID%3a+f0292157-ffad-472d-8119-3cd05518654c%0d%0aTimestamp%3a+2018-02-13+15%3a01%3a54Z%0d%0a`

Looking at Application Insights, I see error:

```
A claim could not be found for lookup claim with id "objectId" defined in 
technical profile with id "AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" policy 
"B2C_1A_SignUpOrSignInUsingSalesforce" of tenant "xyz.onmicrosoft.com".
```

I've followed the tutorial [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-sf-app-custom) and double checked lots of things, but not sure it this issue is due to invalid UserJourney or ClaimsProvider/TechnicalProfile. Or is it just that I'm missing respective user in Azure B2C that I have in Salesforce?

I don't at least see 'objectId' incoming in saml:Assertion:

```
<saml:Assertion xmlns:samlp=\""urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol\"" xmlns:xsi=\""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"" ID=\""_b0b0193ce1e861e13ec39f9a991cb3501518533690616\"" Version=\""2.0\"" IssueInstant=\""2018-02-13T14:54:50.616Z\"" xmlns:saml=\""urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion\""><saml:Issuer Format=\""urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity\"">https://XYZ.my.salesforce.com</saml:Issuer><saml:Subject><saml:NameID Format=\""urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient\"">jussi.palo@XYZ.com</saml:NameID><saml:SubjectConfirmation Method=\""urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer\""><saml:SubjectConfirmationData NotOnOrAfter=\""2018-02-13T14:59:50.616Z\"" Recipient=\""https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/XYZauthdev.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkBase/samlp/sso/assertionconsumer\"" InResponseTo=\""_50a752dd-244c-4447-9ac9-6338e8bb692e\"" /></saml:SubjectConfirmation></saml:Subject><saml:Conditions NotBefore=\""2018-02-13T14:54:20.616Z\"" NotOnOrAfter=\""2018-02-13T14:59:50.616Z\""><saml:AudienceRestriction><saml:Audience>https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/XYZauthdev.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkBase</saml:Audience></saml:AudienceRestriction></saml:Conditions><saml:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant=\""2018-02-13T14:54:50.616Z\""><saml:AuthnContext><saml:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:unspecified</saml:AuthnContextClassRef></saml:AuthnContext></saml:AuthnStatement><saml:AttributeStatement><saml:Attribute Name=\""userId\"" NameFormat=\""urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified\""><saml:AttributeValue xsi:type=\""xs:anyType\"">0050N0000060rpy</saml:AttributeValue></saml:Attribute><saml:Attribute Name=\""username\"" NameFormat=\""urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified\""><saml:AttributeValue xsi:type=\""xs:anyType\"">jussi.palo@XYZ.com</saml:AttributeValue></saml:Attribute><saml:Attribute Name=\""email\"" NameFormat=\""urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified\""><saml:AttributeValue xsi:type=\""xs:anyType\"">jussi.palo@XYZ.com</saml:AttributeValue></saml:Attribute><saml:Attribute Name=\""is_portal_user\"" NameFormat=\""urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified\""><saml:AttributeValue xsi:type=\""xs:anyType\"">false</saml:AttributeValue></saml:Attribute></saml:AttributeStatement></saml:Assertion>
```

For some reason, the User Journey Player isn't showing anything, so I'm thus far been stuck with Application Insights.

Comment: Can you confirm User got created in your tenant (check from users and groups blade) or not? The general flow of External IDP like 1. Re-direct user to IDP login page  2. On successful login, if the user is first-time login B2C will show self-asserted page and it will create the user in tenant  3. B2C read user from local tenant and send out claims it also send claims from IDP if you have written policy to send

Comment: Thanks. Looks like it was confusion on what Starter Pack policy files should be used with the Salesforce instructions. Turned out using "SocialAndLocalAccounts" policy files as a basis did the trick, so my UserJourney was not right at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it was confusion on what Starter Pack policy files should be used with the Salesforce instructions. Turned out using "SocialAndLocalAccounts" policy files as a basis did the trick, so my UserJourney was not right at first.

I will leave the question here for anyone else running into similar error messages.